# Obter imagem de site externo como data:image/jpeg;base64

Tags: data, canvas, base64, img

Será que é possível salvar uma imagem como data de site externo usando javascript ou php? pois esta foi a unica forma que consegui para q a imagem aparecesse no navegador, 
ao inspecionar esse é o caminho:

http://appsite/caminho/caminho2/Content/caminho3/Painelimg/2018_03_02/08_03_28.PNG

Porém quando jogo direto no navegador a imagem fica preta, só q no site da empresa ela é preta mas contem números, deve ser canvas, só consigo ver esses números quando eu salvo com o botão direito do mouse e clicar em "salvar imagem como:" ou outra forma foi abrir a imagem no sources painel e copiar a imagem como data URI ai colei no navegador e lá estava a imagem perfeitamente, no código fica preto também.

OBS: essa imagem muda a cada 10 segundos preciso que meu navegador atualize automaticamente e pegue a próxima imagem. (o nome da imagem é a hora atual H_M_S.PNG ou seja essa em questão foi ás 08h 03m e 28s.

Answer (score 1):

Traduzindo do [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url) inglês:

Se você tem **allow_url_fopen** setado como **true**:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Senão use **cURL**:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Tópico está [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url).

Comment: mas por exemplo, a minha dúvida é por exempo se pego o código da imagem direto url = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QX..." eu consigo fazer aparecer na minha pagina e fazer o download, porém ao passar 10 segundos será outra imagem e assim sucessivamente será que daria para colocar uma variavel que sempre pegara esse valor? data:imagem..... e assim pegara o valor da proxima imagem depois de 10 segundos da outra...

Comment: Não consigo comentar lá na sua pergunta pois não tenho reputação suficiente, mas o endereço que você deu da imagem não funciona aqui. Alguma chance de você salvar localmente no seu servidor a imagem? Que projeto exatamente você está fazendo?